# LINQ - sub query using OrderBy and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have some customers and related orders.

Sometimes I want to see all orders for every customer - straightforward enough.

Other times I'd like to see the last order for every customer, if they have no orders I want to see them anyway.

Heres my LINQ pseudo code :

```
from customers in DataSet.Customers
join orders in DataSet.Orders on customers.CustomerId equals orders.CustomerId
into customerOrders
let customerLastOrder = customerOrders.Select(CustomerId, OrderAmount)
                                      .OrderByDescending(OrderTimestamp)
                                      .GroupBy(CustomerId)
```

I then want to total all Customer Last Orders.

I'm not quite there as you can see - any help really appreciated.

Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
from customer in DataSet.Customers
join order in DataSet.Orders on customer.CustomerId equals order.CustomerId
    into customerOrders
select new {
    CustomerId = customer.Id,
    LastOrderId = customerOrders.OrderByDescending(order => order.OrderTimestamp)
                                .Select(order => order.OrderId)
                                .FirstOrDefault()
};
```

There's no need to perform any more grouping - the group join (`join ... into`) has already done that for you. You're looking at the orders for a single customer, so you just need to order them, select the ID, and then use `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first value in the ordered sequence (or null if the sequence is empty).

Note that I changed the name of your range variable - at any one point, `customer` refers to a single customer, and `order` refers to a single order. It's worth keeping that sort of thing clear in your query for readability.

Comment: Excellent, sure Thank you - then it will be a simple case off looping through the returned rows to get the total?

Comment: @Joe.Net: Yes - but if you're only interested in the total last orders, why do you need customers with no orders?

Comment: Ok Thanks. I need to view Customers regardless of if they have Orders or not - but I can do that in another peice of LINQ then join the 2 together..

Answer (score 2):

I was playing around and came up with:

```
var sumAmounts = Orders.OrderBy(o => o.CustomerId)
                       .ThenByDescending(o => o.DateStamp)
                       .DistinctBy(o => o.CustomerId)
                       .Sum(o => o.OrderAmount);
```

**DistinctBy** comes from Mr Skeet on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

This covers your requirement of totalling 'all Customer Last Orders'.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi christofr - this isn't quite right - it sums all customer orders, it doesn't sum the last Customer Orders - each CustomerId must be unique..

Comment: Hi, the DistinctBy should take care of that -I've pasted my code to here: http://pastebin.com/z8T7AMGV - the output is 50, as I would expect.

Comment: Ah Yes- thanks for the code - that's really helped my understanding - I would up vote more if I could!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use

```
customerOrders.OrderByDescending(OrderTimestamp)
              .GroupBy(CustomerId)
              .Select(c => new { CustomerId = c.Key, LastOrder = c.Last() });
```

although you might be better using Aggregate() to build the customer ID to last order ID mapping, which would avoid the sort and use only a single scan.